# Anyone have a script for the 'Copy To' command with a log message?

Tags: svn

Does anyone have a script for the `Copy To...` command with a log message? We copy to our `tags` folder often and I was looking to automate it with a script for certain folders.

Comment: Please can you indicate which subversion client you are using ? Anyway, did you try to use the "svn copy" command line in a script ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use `svn copy`.

```
svn copy http://host/repos/project/trunk http://host/repos/project/tags/TagName-1.4.5 -m "Tag Release 1.4.5"
```

Found here:http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Subversion.html